# Manage shared folder for office365 Migartion

Tags: exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365

We have setup Hybrid and in the process for migration, the issue here is shared mailbox.
Lets say I migrated a mailbox but users who has access to share mailbox cannot access it and if I migrate the shared mailbox another user cannot access it

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of Exchange on-premises server? Exchange 2013?

For Office 365 hybrid delegation to work as expected, multiple requirements must be met. For example:

[image]

What is the permission for shared mailbox?
Not all mailbox permissions are fully supported in an Exchange hybrid environment. You could refer to the followings:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/permissions
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/delegates/overview-delegation-office-365-hybrid

Comment: exchange 2010..

Comment: Exchange 2010 SP3 servers need the following:
• The latest update rollup (RU), or the immediately previous RU, installed. Exchange 2010 SP3 servers running older RU aren't supported and may not work with delegated mailbox permissions in a hybrid deployment.
• On-premises remote mailboxes associated with Office 365 mailboxes need to be configured to support ACLs. This needs to be done for each on-premises remote mailbox that's associate with an Office 365 mailbox.  Suggest upgrate to Exchange 2016 due to Exchange 2010 will end the support life.